# Why does a runtime error '9' (division by zero) occur where there is no division

Tags: excel, vba, macos

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Degrees(MaxTheta) > 45 Then
```

Vba breaks on this line the first time the sub runs after the workbook is opened. When vba breaks, the variable MaxTheta had a value of 0.481710873550436. A message box presents: "Runtime error '9': divisibility by zero" and highlights the above line. The above line does not contain a 0 or even a division for that matter. The odd thing this is the error only occurs once after the workbook is opened and when the project is reset and the sub run again the error does not occur.
To clarify, the error occurs for all values of MaxTheta and I have searched all lines of code and cells containing formulas for divisibility by zero.

When I split the lines into the following, vba broke on the second line (deg = Application.Wor...)

```
 Dim deg As Double
 deg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Degrees(MaxTheta)
 If deg > 45 Then
```

In the immediate window I typed ?Application.WorksheetFunction.Degrees(MaxTheta) and it gave me 27.6 - even while the above line was broken for divisibility by zero.

Why does this error occur and (if possible) how can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that *MaxTheta* is declared as a long or integer. If this is the case, then it cannot contain the decimal portion of a whole number, only the integer portion. When it is a decimal below *1* or `Int(MaxTheta)` or `CInt(MaxTheta)` (when MaxTheta is less than 0.5) it is resolved to *zero*.  Solution: declare *MaxTheta* as a **double**. The [DEGREES function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/degrees-function-2e74aa0b-10bb-4fca-b506-82263c9b931d) can use a double as the  parameter

Comment: MaxTheta is a double.